# How to avoid query execution timeout in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am running a below update query on a table with 10M records,

```
update table1 t1 set col1=(select coalesce((select t2.col2 from table1 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4 limit 1), null));
```

When I am running above query I am getting the below exception because it is taking so much time to execute the query,

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:146) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:115) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:283) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1719) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:201) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:622) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:458) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:406) ~[postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar:9.4.1207.jre7]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:523) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:520) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way I can simply say that, "Just fire the query and don't wait for the response" so that I can avoid socket timeout? I am using spring provided JDBC Template.

Comment: The coalesce seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you two pragmatic solutions for this:

1. Execute the query in a `new Thread(){...}.start()`. Even better would be to create lightweight `Runnable`s and give them to a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`
2. use a typesafe query constructor language like for example JOOQ or QueryDSL. JOOQ can generate type-safe classes from the database for you to create your queries. These classes have all the asynchronous implementations you need: `dsl.update(TABLE1).set(...).executeAsync()`

But still, one main question remains: Do you want to avoid the socket timeout or do you want to ignore it?

The above is for *ignoring* the socket-timeout.
The following solutions may fit better by *avoiding* the socket-timeout:

1. Catch the error and react to it. For example: Tell the user, that the number of records to update is too many.
2. Split the `update` statements into several batches (in the background), so the update will always succeed. (there are tools to do this for you easily. JOOQ can do also that for you)